# Setting a sub-option to clang-tidy

Tags: clang-tidy

I am using clang-tidy from cmdline `clang-tidy readability-implicit-bool-conversion ... <other_options>"`.
This clang-tidy option has the sub-option `AllowPointerConditions`, in order for clang-tidy to allow me to use `if (!p)` whithot warnings.

https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-implicit-bool-conversion.html

How can I enable this from the command line? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-config` option and put the additional options into `CheckOptions`.

```
clang-tidy -config="{Checks: '-*,readability-implicit-bool-conversion', 
  CheckOptions: [{key: readability-implicit-bool-conversion.AllowPointerConditions, value: 1} ]}" 
  test.cpp -- -std=c++11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a *.clang-tidy* yaml configuration file this is how you set check options

```yaml
FormatStyle: file
Checks: >
  # all enabled or disabled checks ...
CheckOptions:
  - key: readability-implicit-bool-conversion.AllowPointerConditions
    value: 1
  - key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.Threshold
    value: 10
  - key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.IgnoreMacros
    value: true
```